# How To Convert base64 String to PDF in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, base64

I have a base 64 string that is coming from an API call. I am testing with a sample base64 string and I am trying to convert it to pdf or an image to view in my react.js website.

I've tried many solutions, but nothing seems to work. I found a react js package that is called `base64topdf` I installed it and tried to decode the base64 string to PDF, but it gives me this error `"TypeError: fs.writeFileSync is not a function"`

I don't know what i am doing wrong.

How can I convert a base64 string to a PDF or an image in reactjs?

Documentation to the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64topdf

Here is my code:

```
 const base64 = require('base64topdf');

 const base64STR = "JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9M...." //base64 string

 const decodedBase64 = base64.base64Decode(base64STR, 'waybill');

 console.log(decodedBase64)
```

Comment: @ikhvjs thats a completely different thing, i want to convert to PDF

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this
`` <embed src={`data:application/pdf;base64,${base64STR}`} /> ``

Comment: Thank you this worked!

Comment: It works also for other type of files like pptx, docs etc.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use this [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64topdf), since it is written for Node.js not for web development. If you go inside the package source code you will see that it is using the `fs` module or file system.

https://github.com/rpsankar001/base64topdf/blob/master/index.js#L3

---

For the web, you can use something like this:

```js
function downloadPDF(pdf) {
    const linkSource = `data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "file.pdf";

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
}
```

---

Worth mentioning, React has an upcoming feature called Server Components, that will allow you to use server-side code with React. It seems that in the near future you will be able to use the package.

See: https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/12/21/data-fetching-with-react-server-components.html

Answer (score -1):

It seems that the functions `base64Decode` and `base64Encode` should be used in NodeJS only, your React env should not be able to access `fs` or `Buffer`.

Look at he file here: https://github.com/rpsankar001/base64topdf/blob/master/index.js

Also this package seems very empty, I would prefer `const decodedBase64 = atob("JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9M...."); //base64 string`

Comment: Can you please provide a full detailed answer? this doesn't help much it only let me know that i cant use this function in react only in node js

Comment: ok : use `atob` because you are in browser instead of `base64topdf`.